# Getting n values from key values pair using pig

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, apache-pig

I have a test file with key and values separated by coma. How can i get only 10 values for each key using  pig script.

sample input: john|str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7,str8,str9,str10,str11,str2 
,preferred output: john|str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7,str8,str9,str10

Comment: Please edit your question with the sample input, and preferred output. And tell us what you've already tried.

Comment: Please add the additional info along with the question and not as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to do this depending on exactly what you have as input and need as output.  I'm assuming that you only want the first ten, and the remaining values can just be thrown out.

This is the way I would do it (CL).  It is a little longer than the short way (CF), but the code more clear to me, and allows for more flexibility in naming the schema:

```
A = LOAD 'myData' USING PigStorage('|') AS (name: chararray, vals: chararray) ;  
B = FOREACH A GENERATE name, STRSPLIT(vals, ',') AS svals: () ;  
CL = FOREACH B GENERATE name,
                        svals.($0, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) AS ten ; 
                        -- ten can have a schema, like ten: (a1: chararray, etc.)
                        -- After giving it a schema, you can also flatten it to
                        -- make it like the output of CF, but with better types
```

This is the resulting schema and output for CL:

```
CL: {name: chararray,ten: ()}
(john,(str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7,str8,str9,str10))
```

This way is a little shorter, but makes it harder to apply a schema to the values:

```
-- Uses the same A  
B = FOREACH A GENERATE name AS name, FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(vals, ',')) ;
CF = FOREACH B GENERATE $0 AS name: chararray, $1, $2 .. $10 ;
```

Schema and output for CF:

```
CF: {name: chararray,bytearray,bytearray,bytearray,bytearray,bytearray,bytearray,bytearray,bytearray,bytearray,bytearray}
(john,str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7,str8,str9,str10)
```

Comment: Thanks mr2ert for your help. This script perfectly solved my problem.